# How to check whether memory that was reserved in the device tree has actually been reserved

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The relevant device tree entry that I am using is:

```
memory {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x40000000>;
};


reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    ranges;

    spw_dma@3E000000 {
        reg = <0x3E000000 0x2000000>;
    };
};
```

Can I check somewhere in the `/sys/class` interface to verify that the memory has actually been reserved? Since I am accessing the memory via the `/dev/mem` interface, I effectively bypass all security measures, and therefore, it would be useful to, at least be able to verify, that no one else will write to that memory region.

*Note: I am aware that The Right Way™ would be to write a kernel driver or use a [dynamic memory UIO driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48538357/6783666)*

Comment: you should be able to see in /proc/iomem, if that is used by a driver (the reserved memory regions are/needs to be used by device/driver), refer http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Linux+Reserved+Memory and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt for mor info.

Comment: Thanks for the /proc/mem pointer. I only have "kernel code" and "kernel data" entries, so it is probably not being reserved. I guess, it is mandatory to specify the compatible field, to have DT entries be applied. Is there a catch-all solution for that?

Comment: NO there isnt any catch all solution, but what you can do write a simple driver and reserve it. Also as simpler solution would be to use memmap which reserve you (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)